# Скрыть строку с цифрами в EditText с паролем

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

Как можно скрыть строку с цифрами (выделенная на скриншоте область), если у `EditText` установлено `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textPassword"`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_password"
    style="@style/CustomTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/hint_password"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textPassword"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:privateImeOptions="nm"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в ваш `editText`

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```